# How do I make Mongo findOneAndModify only a single document?

Tags: mongodb

The documentation states that findAndModify will return multiple queries if it applies.

How do I findOne document and update it in a single call?

Comment: use _id for your query. it will find just one

Comment: If I use _id it will expect to have an _id set.. How do I specify "any _id"?

Comment: According to the docs `findAndModify will only select one document to modify` and will return the original document.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is? What does "return multiple queries if it applies" mean? `findAndModify` will return at most 1 document under all circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
db.coll.find({query}).limit(1).forEach(function(item)
{
   db.coll.findAndModify({_id : item._id}, update});
})
```

the `db.coll.find` will find you just one document and you can modify it.

`db.coll.findOne({query})` is really `db.coll.find({query})` with below syntax, and there is no performance benefit for it in mongo.

```
// findOne() method  body. it uses find() method in it
function (query, fields, options) {
    var cursor = this.find(query, fields, -1, 0, 0, options);
    if (!cursor.hasNext()) {
        return null;
    }
    var ret = cursor.next();
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        throw "findOne has more than 1 result!";
    }
    if (ret.$err) {
        throw "error " + tojson(ret);
    }
    return ret;
}
```